# telnet connection using PHP

Tags: php, telnet

I need to write a PHP script to telnet to a router, run a command and fetch the results. does anyone know a telnet connection library in PHP?

**Update:** This request (as is obvious) was for a long time ago. In the end I had to write the client library that I needed myself. The code for this library (and many more modules) is open source and available on [github](https://github.com/farzadghanei/POLlib/blob/master/Parsonline/Network/Telnet.php).
Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: Why is missing the username and password options???

Answer (score 7):

There is a lovely class available for PHP telnet connectivity on Nicholas Hall's Github:
https://github.com/ngharo/Random-PHP-Classes/blob/master/Telnet.class.php

Answer (score 5):

using stdin/stream_select & blocking streams gives you a 20 lines telnet like client

```
<?

$socket = fsockopen("192.168.52.1", 8000);

if(!$socket)return;
stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, 0);

do {
  echo "$ ";
  $read   = array( $socket, STDIN); $write  = NULL; $except = NULL;

  if(!is_resource($socket)) return;
  $num_changed_streams = @stream_select($read, $write, $except, null);
  if(feof($socket)) return ;


  if($num_changed_streams  === 0) continue;
  if (false === $num_changed_streams) {
      /* Error handling */
    var_dump($read);
    echo "Continue\n";
    die;
  } elseif ($num_changed_streams > 0) {
    echo "\r";
    $data = fread($socket, 4096);
    if($data !== "") 
      echo "<<< $data";

    $data2 = fread(STDIN, 4096);

    if($data2 !== "") {
      echo ">>> $data2";
      fwrite($socket, trim($data2));
    }
  }

} while(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pear::Net_Socket: http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket
Extend this class for a simple PHP telnet bot or session.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';
// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = '127.0.0.1';
$ftp_user_name = 'Till';
$ftp_user_pass = 'Kcp05';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// login with username and password
ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
// upload a file
ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII);
// close the connection
echo "$file sent to $ftp_server as $remote_file\n<br/>";
ftp_close($conn_id);


// finished copying the input.dat to the till now, just need to execute the print command.
// That will copy somefile.txt in the same folder as this .php file to the ftp server root dir.


$header1=chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x1F).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x20).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x18).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x27).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFD).chr(0x01).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFB).chr(0x03).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFD).chr(0x03).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFC).chr(0x23).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFC).chr(0x24).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFA).chr(0x1F).chr(0x00).chr(0x50).chr(0x00).chr(0x18).chr(0xFF).chr(0xF0).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFA).chr(0x20).chr(0x00).chr(0x33).chr(0x38).chr(0x34).chr(0x30).chr(0x30).chr(0x2C).chr(0x33).chr(0x38).chr(0x34).chr(0x30).chr(0x30).chr(0xFF).chr(0xF0).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFA).chr(0x27).chr(0x00).chr(0xFF).chr(0xF0).chr(0xFF).chr(0xFA).chr(0x18).chr(0x00).chr(0x58).chr(0x54).chr(0x45).chr(0x52).chr(0x4D).chr(0xFF).chr(0xF0);

$fp=pfsockopen("127.0.0.1",23);

echo "Telnet session opening ...";

sleep(4);

fputs($fp,$header1); 
sleep(4); 

fputs($fp,"Till\r");
sleep(2); 
fputs($fp,"Kcp05\r"); 

sleep(2);
fputs($fp,"notepad\r"); 

sleep(3);

echo "Telnet session closing ...";

fclose($fp);

?>
```

that worked for me. the first part will upload the ftp file to the server, and the second  part will lo onto the telnet server, and execute a program that can use the file you just uploaded by ftp. tested it just now.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the $header1 string? Does this send some sort of Telnet protocol configuration commands, or am I reading too far into your example?

Comment: This should explain the  $header1 I suppose. http://mars.netanya.ac.il/~unesco/cdrom/booklet/HTML/NETWORKING/node300.html