# Not able to launch putty with telnet session using php

Tags: php

I have putty.exe on my desktop so if I will go to command prompt and then to  `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop` location and execute following command it will launch the Putty window of telnet connection to server specified:

`putty.exe telnet://a.b.c.d/`

I am trying to launch the putty to telnet to specific server using following but its not working for me:

```
<?php
$securecrt = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\putty.exe telnet://a.b.c.d/ ";


exec($securecrt);
?>

If I try following then it launches the putty application but will have to provide the host name or IP to login:

<?php
$securecrt = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\putty.exe ";


exec($securecrt);
?>
```

Not sure if I am missing something very basic, It will be great if someone can help with this.

Comment: The question seems to miss how you're trying it. But a wild guess: You're running PHP in a Web server as service. There's no desktop then.

Comment: This question is not really related to programming.

Comment: I am using wampserver on my xp desktop. I am trying to trigger something or launch something using PHP program and its not working.

Comment: Does it have to be with putty? http://stackoverflow.com/q/905348/664479 has a solution...

Comment: with putty I will be able to give user option to interact and execute other commands if they require, with fsock not sure if I will be able to.

Comment: Code is very simple code to launch the telnet using putty

Comment: <?php 

$securecrt = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\putty.exe\t-telnet a.b.c.d";
echo "SecureCRT execu\n<BR>"; 

exec($securecrt);
?>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Putty, you could try to use PHP with fsock or use a class like http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/

However, you can try the following using your current setup:

```
$securecrt = '"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\putty.exe" telnet://a.b.c.d/';
```

Comment: nope it didnt help! it doesnt even launch the putty.exe application.